# "on" or "with" ? Which preposition to use?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition can be used in this sentence?

> the curtains are hanging ...... the hooks.

with or on? which preposition is right to use here. And how would each change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Why are the choices limited to “with” and “on”? Things can hang “from” a hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'With' means the curtains and hooks are in the same location, and the curtains (at least) are hanging. It would only be appropriate if there were, for example, a package of hooks in a store and you asked where the curtains were.

If you mean that the curtains are being supported by the hooks, then 'on' is the only appropriate word of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think in what situation a curtain can be hanging WITH a hook. The purpose of a hook is to hold something, so here a hook would hold the curtain.Therefore  "The curtains are hanging ON the hooks" is correct if the curtain is using, and requires, the hook to keep itself on the rail.

"With" would be not an accurate description because both the hook and the curtain cannot hold up themselves independently.

Comment: Another sense of **with** indicates the means used to accomplish something, as in "she cut the curtain **with** a pair of scissors", "the hook was held in place **with** glue". This is likely the sense that the OP is asking about.